# Are there differences between xvfb and xvfb-run?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, xvfb

I have to install a program which requires xvfb-run.

But I can't install xvfb-run by commanding 'sudo apt-get install xvfb-run' on Ubuntu 16.04.

However, I can install xvfb.

Are there differences between xvfb and xvfb-run ?

Can I use xvfb instead of xvfb-run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xvfb-run.1.html implies that xvfb-run is a wrapper around Xvfb.  So, you could certainly use Xvfb without xvfb-run, you just have to pass a lot more arguments / options that xvfb-run would handle for you.

But looking at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/xvfb (which is the package the man page lists for 16.04LTS), that package should come with xvfb-run.

> This package also contains a convenience script called xvfb-run which 
>   simplifies the automated execution of X clients in a virtual server 
>   environment. This convenience script requires the use of the xauth 
>   program.

So, are you sure that if you do apt-get install xvfb, you don't have xvfb-run installed as well?  (You might need to install something to get xauth, but I would have expected that to be handled as a dependency)